# elasticsearch - querying multiple indexes is possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster with 3 indexes:

```
/users/user
/events/visit
/events/register
/pages/page
```

So, now I need to run queries processing multiple indexes.

Eg: **Get gender of users registered in page X.**
(*To get this info, I need infos from multiple indexes.*)

Is this possible? Maybe integrating hadoop?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is quite easy within Elasticsearch itself! Anytime you would specify an index, you can separate additional indices by comma.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_search?q=yourQueryHere'
```

You can also search all indices with _all.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=yourQueryHere'
```

Here's some helpful documentation from elasticsearch's website. This site has TONS of info, but it is a bit difficult to find sometimes, IMO.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html

Comment: I found information that _all will be deprecated (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) , but I'm not sure if elastic search has several uses for "_all", so perhaps it's a fake new :D, please update your answer @brian-mego if you know something about it

Comment: can we do it for the date range like CURL -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index_2018-12-{15-25}/_search' means I wanted to select only data from index 15 to 25 not more or else, I have the index for per day basis.

Comment: @IndrajeetGour, the [conventions for multiple indices doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) says it support wildcards, like `*` and `-`, but it doesn't mention about range

Comment: you can create alias and hook all indices behind it. query to alias and get all relevant docs.

Comment: @Brian Can we limit result on the basis of an index. Suppose we want the top 5 results from index1 and the top 5 from index2. Can we achieve this in elastic search.

Comment: Thx for the `_all` hint!

Answer (score 8):

By not limiting our search to a particular index or type, we have searched across all documents in the cluster. Elasticsearch forwarded the search request in parallel to a primary or replica of every shard in the cluster.

```
       1)/users,events,pages/_search : Search all types in the users,events and pages

       2)/u*,e*,p*/_search : Search all types in any indices beginning with u,e or beginning with p

       3)/events/visit,register/_search : Search types visit and register in the events index

       4) /_all/user,visit,register,page/_search : Search types users,events and pages in specified indices
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do search query through multiple indices:

for example:

```
curl -X POST \
'http://localhost:9200/test1,test2/_search?pretty=' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query": {
    ...
    }
}
'
```