# Elasticsearch multiple indexes search via URI example needed

Tags: elasticsearch, uri

I need and example request for URI search in elasticsearch for multiple indexes using a wildcard

in sense:
GET index_name_*/_search => translates to in http

Comment: I think this answers your question. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315753/elasticsearch-querying-multiple-indexes-is-possible?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

**curl -X GET "hostname:9200/index_name_*/_search"**

or **http://hostname:9200/index_name_*/_search**