# Join-like query for multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have 2 entities stored in **separate** indexes:

- `City` index has 2 fields mapping: `name:keyword` and `url:text`.
- `Product` index has 2 fields mapping: `name:keyword` and `city:text`

I would like to query all `Product`s by `City`'s url.

Example:

```
Given: Search all shirts by url "http://shirts-shop.com/frankfurt"

Then (step 1): Search all cities where url is "http://shirts-shop.com/frankfurt" — it will return "Frankfurt" city

Then (step 2): Search all shirts by city "Frankfurt"
```

In SQL databases it is quite simple to write: we just need to use 'join' query. How to write such query in ElasticSearch **6.5** ?

*WARN*: Entities are in separate indexes, because as said in documentation  ElasticSearch starting from version **6** recommends to use [1 index per mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

Comment: I guess you can solve your problem referring to this previously asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315753/elasticsearch-querying-multiple-indexes-is-possible

Comment: You are on the right way but I know that it is possible. I don't know how to write such query. Also, imagine if entities have fields with same name: what to do then? I am a bit newbie in ES.

Comment: You can specify your desired fields inside your query by referring to index by dot. like this `city.name` or `product.name`. Your query must be something like this: `{"query": {"bool": [{"must": [{"match": {"city.name": "frankfurt"}}, {"match": {"product.name": "whatever" } } ] } ] } }`

Comment: I see only 1 single solution for this: use external service which will call appropriate requests

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the url gives the name of city.

```
i.e. http://shirts-shop.com/<_city_>
```

From this we can extract city name
In the index **Product** I would suggest to keep the data-type of ***city*** as ***keyword*** instead of ***text*** (so that it doesn't get analyzed).

To get shirts in <*_city_*> use the term query:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "city": <_city_>
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```