# Is it possible to merge to create a document C from document A and B with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, document

My problem is that I need to perform sorting from data coming from two different datasource, a MySQL database which contains information about some products and a PostgreSQL that contains some metrics linked to these products.

Because the data resides in two different datasources I cannot out of the box come up with a single performant query that would make the ordering (pagination) at database level. 
I need to make two different queries and then manually merge the data and perform sorting and pagination code side.
I would like to avoid as much as possible having to create a custom pagination system and a manual data merging and as much as possible delegate this job to the underlying database.

This is where I thought a system such as ElasticSearch (or Solr, but ES seems to be easier to use) could help.

1) Does ES provide tools or mechanism to merge 2 datasource into 1 document ? Or this job needs to be done by a 3rd party tool that will peridocally pull the data from both datasource and create / update the documents?

2) I'm correct to assume that having 2 indices (or 2 different doc type) is pointless in my case since ES cannot perform join queries ?

3) Apart from creating one single document what other solution do I have that ES can help with? Is it possible 'somehow' that with having datasource1 data in an index1 and datasource2 data in an index2 I can perform multiple search queries using both the index at the same time (since join is a no go).

Answer (score 0):

> Does ES provide tools or mechanism to merge 2 datasource into 1 document ? Or this job needs to be done by a 3rd party tool that will peridocally pull the data from both datasource and create / update the documents?

There are two approaches to accomplish this :

1. An ETL process (Extract, Transform, Load) to load data from both sources into one single document. In the Elastic world you can use [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html) to accomplish this
2. [Data Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_virtualization) is supposed to do this without the need to copy the data

> 3) Apart from creating one single document what other solution do I have that ES can help with? Is it possible 'somehow' that with having datasource1 data in an index1 and datasource2 data in an index2 I can perform multiple search queries using both the index at the same time (since join is a no go).

It's very easy to perform a single query through multiple indices. [Answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315753/elasticsearch-querying-multiple-indexes-is-possible)