# How to store equipment information along with streaming data in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

We have some equipment meta data - Like vendor , price , contact etc along with streaming data coming from that equipment sensors ... how do we store this in ES , should be use separate index for meta and one for streaming ? Can we still query across indices to fetch appropriate information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Meta as well as Near Run Time(stream) data at the same index and query it.(preferred)
Even If you design to have separate indices for them you can query across the indices to fetch appropriate information.You can use [Alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-aliases.html), an index alias is simply a grouping of a number of indexes under a single logical alias name[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315753/elasticsearch-querying-multiple-indexes-is-possible)